# When closing one of the Multi opened instances of Excel that I have Before close code runs

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a little issue which is kind of strange.

So I have a macro Workbook (lets call it "Main" for simplification) with all its code that runs almost perfectly except for this little problem. "Main" is usually always open as it is our balances for the day.

When I or another user opens any other workbook at the same time as this one is open everything is fine, but when we close the workbook that doesn't have the code, "Main" runs it's  before close code.

So this is my before Close code I have on "Main":

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Tsweep As Integer
Dim sTime As Date
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coordenador").Range("O2") <> "" Then
For Tsweep = 2 To Range("Coordenador!O1048000").End(xlUp).Row

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Range("Coordenador!O" & Tsweep).Value, 
Procedure:="CloseC", Schedule:=False

Next Tsweep
End If
CloseC
sTime = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coordenador").Range("P15") + 
TimeValue("00:30:00")
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=sTime, Procedure:="SaveWb", Schedule:=False
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub[/CODE]
```

This is the code on "CloseC":

```
Sub CloseC()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Coordenador")

With ws
.Unprotect Password:=pass
.Range("O:O").ClearContents
End With

For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Worksheet.Protect Password:=pass
Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coordenador").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LookupList").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

And the Code on SaveWb:

```
Sub SaveWb()
Dim vTime As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Coordenador")

ThisWorkbook.Save
vTime = Now

With ws
.Unprotect Password:=pass
.Range("P15") = vTime
.Protect Password:=pass
End With

Application.OnTime vTime + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "SaveWb"
End Sub
```

To explain this code stops all the OnTime runs that the system might still have. It clears some cells, protects some sheets and it saves. The error than appears when the user closes "Main" and excel tries to run "SaveWb".

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this since in theory excel runs each instance by itself and even though me and/or the users are closing these other workbooks with the close button top we are not closing "Main" and that workbook remains open. Other idea would be to check if the workbook is still open after 5 seconds and if it is to run "SaveWb" but I haven't found a way to code that.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you considered checking the name of the workbook at the beginning of the BeforeClose sub? Also, what is ThisWorkbook? Is it your alias for ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: @MaciejLipinski `ThisWorkbook` is a built-in object referring to the workbook containing the macros.

Comment: @YowE3K thanks, I did not know that - I always used ActiveWorkbook or referred to the code workbook by its filename

Comment: Maciej gave me an idea. I could only run the code if ThisWorkbook was the ActiveWorkbook, however this prompts me another question, after a user clicks the close button does the active workbook change first or would the beforeclose run first? (being this a code from a different workbook, i hope I'm being clear..)

Comment: If the Workbook_BeforeClose event procedure responds to an Application event it would be appropriate that it should run when any workbook is closed. The only way to prevent it from taking action would be by limiting its applicability to specifically named (in the code) workbooks. On the other hand, if the closed workbooks contain code it seems possible that their code might call a procedure in "Main's" VBA Project. You might prevent that by placing `Option Private Module` at the top of the code modules which you don't want to be visible to other projects.

Comment: @Variatus The way to limit it to run as you can see above I thought of it only runing the before close when the workbook is active. Though I wonder if it will proceed on the right order of things as I have already mentioned. I am not worried with other macro workbooks as this will be the only one

Comment: That would be the way to go if it is an Application event that triggers the code. If it isn't you may feel more comfortable if you find out why the code runs at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work around for this. Thank you all for helping me reach the idea.

Basicly what I did was add a If clause at the start of the before close:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "ReportingReport*" Then
(code)
Else SaveWb
End If
```